# Prove that $\frac d {dz} \ln(\Gamma(z)) ∼ \ln(z) − \frac 1{2\,z}$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, gamma-function

What steps do I take to figure this out?

I've tried using this: $z!\sim \sqrt{2\,\pi\,z} \left(\frac z e\right)^2$

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument)

Comment: Please put the entire argument of $sqrt$ in braces {}

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2116694. Also, you have a typo in Stirling's formula.